# Numba corrupts data by affecting in-place

Tags: python, numpy, numba

Numba and NumPy don't execute the following `foo` function in the same way:

```
from numba import jit
import numpy as np

@jit
def foo(a):
    a[:] = a[::-1] # reverse the array

a = np.array([0, 1, 2])
foo(a)
print(a)
```

With NumPy (without `@jit`) it prints `[2, 1, 0]`, while with Numba (with `@jit`) it prints `[2, 1, 2]`. It looks like Numba modifies the array in-place, which leads in data corruption. It is easy to work around by making a copy of the array:

```
a[:] = a[::-1].copy()
```

But is this the desired behavior? Shouldn't Numba and NumPy give the same result?

I am using Numba v0.26.0 in Python 3.5.2.

Comment: I don't think you can rely on the behavior you saw from the non-jitted version. I'm surprised it worked, and I know there are very similar (non-jitted) cases where you get behavior more like what you saw from Numba.

Comment: If you try it with something like `+=` instead of `=`, you get the Numba-like behavior.

Comment: So maybe NumPy recognizes we want to reverse the array and has a special code for doing that in-place properly.

Comment: I suspect `a[:] = a[::-1]` is a poor candidate for `numba` improvement.  That expression uses a couple of compiled operations; it doesn't involve Python level iteration.

Comment: This strikes me as a bug, or at least a missing feature, in Numba. Numpy is doing special work here to try and do what you probably intended. Perhaps numba should learn to do that work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue (https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/1960) and it was fixed in numba 0.27.  Following NumPy behavior, the fix detects for overlap and makes temporary copies to avoid corrupting the data.

Answer (score 1):

Your `jit` has the same sort of in-place problems that this Python loop does.

```
In [718]: x=list(range(3))
In [719]: for i in range(3):
     ...:     x[i] = x[2-i]
In [720]: x
Out[720]: [2, 1, 2]
```

The `x[:] = x[::-1]` is buffered, not because numpy recognizes that something special is happening, but because it always uses some sort of buffering with doing assignments.

The Python interpreter translates `[]` notation into calls to `__setitem__` and `__getitem__`.  So 681 and 682 do the same thing:

```
In [680]: x=np.arange(3)
In [681]: x[:] = x[::-1]
In [682]: x.__setitem__(slice(None), x.__getitem__(slice(None,None,-1)))
In [683]: x
Out[683]: array([0, 1, 2])
```

That means that `x[::-1]` is evaluated in full - to a temporary array, before being copied to `x[:]`.  Now `x[::-1]` is a view, not a copy, so the `setitem` step must do some sort of buffered copy.

Another way to do this copy is with

```
np.copyto(x, x[::-1])
```

Checking the `x.__array_interface__` I see that the data buffer address remains the same.  So it is doing a copy, not just changing the data buffer address.  But it's in low level compiled code.

Usually buffering is just a implementation issue that users don't need to worry about. [ufunc.at](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) is designed to deal with cases where that buffering creates problems.  This topic comes up periodically; search for `add.at`.

=============

Note that Python lists behave the same way.  The translation to 'get/setitem' is the same.

```
In [699]: x=list(range(3))
In [700]: x[:] = x[::-1]
In [701]: x
Out[701]: [2, 1, 0]
```

======================

I'm not entirely sure this is relevant or not, but since I tested these ideas I'll document them.  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html suggests using `np.nditer` as a stepping stone for implementing iterative tasks in `cython`.

A first stab at using `nditer` is:

```
In [769]: x=np.arange(5)
In [770]: it = np.nditer((x,x[::-1]), op_flags=[['readwrite'], ['readonly']])
In [771]: for i,j in it:
     ...:     print(i,j)
     ...:     i[...] = j
     ...:     
0 4
1 3
2 2
3 3
4 4
In [772]: x
Out[772]: array([4, 3, 2, 3, 4])
```

This produces the same sort of overlapping result as `numba`.

Adding a copy makes for a clean reversal.

```
it = np.nditer((x,x[::-1].copy()), op_flags=[['readwrite'], ['readonly']])
```

If I add the `external_loop` flag I also get a clean reversal:

```
In [781]: x=np.arange(5)
In [782]: it = np.nditer((x,x[::-1]), op_flags=[['readwrite'], ['readonly']], fl
     ...: ags = ['external_loop'])
In [783]: for i,j in it:
     ...:     print(i,j)
     ...:     i[...] = j
     ...:     
[0 1 2 3 4] [4 3 2 1 0]
In [784]: x
Out[784]: array([4, 3, 2, 1, 0])
```

Comment: _"`x[::-1]` is evaluated in full - to a temporary array"_ - no it isn't - the result is a temporary view, so I'm not sure this reasoning holds

Comment: I recognized that is a `view`, so that the buffering must be occurring during the `setitem` step, not the `getitem`.

Comment: _"not because numpy recognizes that something special"_ - this actually is the reason, but the special thing is the detection that the arguments to setitem overlap in memory, and so numpy tries to behave as if they didn't (possibly by copying the array)

Comment: The detection is (probably) the same as what [`np.shares_memory`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.shares_memory.html) does

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to tell whether it is taking an extra buffering step in the case of shared memory, or if it is just routinely doing it.  It's not obvious from code in files like `arraytypes.c.src` and `ctors.c`.

Comment: So I understand that in the case of NumPy it works because of the implementation details (some kind of buffering), but it shouldn't really. Then Numba is not doing anything wrong and this is not a bug.

Comment: _"it works because of the implementation details"_ - no, I think it works by design. The only sensible outcome of `a[:] = a[::-1]` is what numpy produces. Why is nothing else sensible? Because the outcome would depend on choice of iteration order and block size of copies - two things that the user hasn't chosen.

Comment: hpaulj: I'd put my money on it not being routine, and only taking the hit of copying if it might need to. `np.may_share_memory` is probably what actually triggers it, because the certain version is expensive to compute

Comment: At the lowest level is the choice between using `memcpy` and `memmove`.  But figuring out which is being used in the `c` source code is tricky.